# X-editable: How to add an extra attribute to the input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I have a link that has [x-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) enabled on it with `data-type="text"`.

I want to add an additional attribute to the `input` field that is created when the item is being edited.

So at the moment x-editable is producing the following input field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="padding-right: 24px;">
```

And I want to add a pattern attribute, so it would look like (adding pattern attr ):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="padding-right: 24px;" pattern="blah">
```

How can I add this extra attribute?

Comment: try look at the documentation http://api.jquery.com/attr/, So basic `$(element).attr("attribute","value")`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I have no way to access the element though, that I can find. I can give the input a class through the editable constructor, however, this input field doesn't exist until the element is clicked on (converted into an input field by x-editable). So if I did `$('.class').attr("pattern", "blah");` then it wouldn't do anything as the `input` isn't there yet. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that every click on the x-editable element you can reach the generated input 
 in the popup by using

```
$('your element').on("click",function(){
  $(this).next().find(".editable-input input").attr("data-pattern","yep 1!")
});
```

See below snippet : using inspect you'll see that the `pattern` attr is present

```js
$(function() {
    $('#username1').editable();
    
    $('#username1').on("click",function(){
      $(this).next().find(".editable-input input").attr("data-pattern","yep 1!")
    });
    
    $('#username2').editable();
    
    $('#username2').on("click",function(){
      $(this).next().find(".editable-input input").attr("data-pattern","yep 2!")
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<a href="#" id="username1" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-title="Enter username">superuser 1</a>
<br><br><br><br>
<a href="#" id="username2" data-type="text" data-pk="2" >superuser 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set any value using `attr` method (We don't have `addAttr` method as we have for class `addClass` we just need to use `element.attr('AttributeName','AttributeValue')`).

If you wish to remove the attribute then you may use the below syntax.

```
  element.removeAttr('AttributeName')
```

```js
$('input').attr('pattern','desiredValue');
alert($('input').attr('pattern'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="padding-right: 24px;">
```

Comment: do comment why negative vote? and explain what is wrong with the answer

Comment: The reply I have put above has the same issue as your answer, wasn't me that downvoted your answer mind.

Comment: Not my vote (don't have the rep for it) but I believe the problem is that your answer is basic the same as the comment in the question

Comment: Okay..@PeterHansen , I haven't seen the comment before i posted my answer

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method from jQuery:

```
$('.input-sm').attr("pattern","blah")
```